# How can I set a local variable using the name of another variable that is in a string in SQL?

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, variables, iteration

I've got a series of 10 variables that I need to iterate through, for example:

```
DECLARE @id1 int, @id2 int, @id3 int, @id4 int...@id10 int
```

Now, each variable holds a different value that I need to iterate through and add that value on another variable.

For example:

```
SET @Total = @Total + @id1
```

Instead of doing that 10 times, is there a way that I can do some sort of for loop or something to iterate and do something like this on each iteration

```
SET @Total = @Total + @id + @counter
```

It would be something like you can do on programming languages

```
Total = Total + Id[i]
```

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like these variables should be a column in a table. Then it's just `select @total = SUM(Column) from Table`

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: nope, you can't do that.

Presumptive answer: What you want is trivial to do with arrays. SQL does not support arrays. (Well, it kinda does if the data is stored in tables, but that's not the case here.)

Detailed answer: you probably could do something like that by loading values into a table and running dynamic code created in a loop, but that's a lot more work than just writing it out as a single ugly statement.

Fishing answer: if you actually have N variable you need to process, plug them into a table and work at it that way (only sensible thing if N is large). I'm guessing this is not the case, though.

Comment: It's not large, it's a maximum of 10 but variable. Sometimes could be 3 and sometimes 7 and so on.

Comment: If it's short and needs to be flexible, use something like @BasicIsaac's solution. I believe it's cleaner and more maintainable (and, yes, ugly) to just write out a lot of turgid code.

Answer (score 0):

It is doable, but not pretty, this is how it will look:

```
DECLARE @id1 int, @id2 int, @id3 int, @id4 int, @id5 int, @id6 int, @id7 int, @id8 int, @id9 int, @id10 int, @Total int, @BigTotal int
DECLARE @rowcount int
DECLARE @varscount int
DECLARE @varname varchar(10)
--This table will hold your vars and their values:
DECLARE @varstable TABLE (
idx int identity(1,1),
varname varchar(10), varval int )

--set your var values any way you like:
SET @id1 = 10
SET @id2 = 10
SET @id3 = 10
SET @id4 = 10
SET @id5 = 10
SET @id6 = 10
SET @id7 = 10
SET @id8 = 10
SET @id9 = 10
SET @id10 = 10
SET @Total = 100

--dump the values and the varname into the table:
insert into @varstable (varname, varval) 
VALUES ('@id1',@id1),
('@id2',@id2),
('@id3',@id3),
('@id4',@id4),
('@id5',@id5),
('@id6',@id6),
('@id7',@id7),
('@id8',@id8),
('@id9',@id9),
('@id10',@id10)


--now loop through the vars and their values:
SET @rowcount = 1
SET @varscount = (SELECT MAX(idx) FROM @varstable)
WHILE(@rowcount < @varscount)
BEGIN

SET @varname = (SELECT varname FROM @varstable WHERE idx = @rowcount)
--here's your action:
SET  @Total = @Total + (SELECT varval FROM @varstable WHERE idx = @rowcount)
--a little success message:
PRINT CONCAT(@varname, ' +  @total = ',@Total)
SET @rowcount = @rowcount + 1
END
```

Cheers